# Call parent function from iframe created with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider this code:

```
function callme() {
    alert('call');
}

$(function(){ 
    var iframe = $('<iframe />').attr('src', 'b.php').appendTo('body'); 
    //call 'callme' function from parent
});
```

I don't want to edit b.php.
Is there any way I can call the parent 'callme' function using just javascript in the parent file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the part "I don't want to edit `b.php`". Your question is asking about how to call the parent function from an iframe and `b.php` is in the iframe. How can you make it call the parent `callme()` without modifying `b.php`?

From `b.php` you can call

```
parent.callme();
```

Or is your question, how can I call `callme()` after `b.php` finishes loading?

Comment: I wish to use the iframe variable and call the method if it's possible .

Comment: @danip Still not clear, what do you mean use the iframe variable? If you just want to call `callme()`, you don't need the `iframe` variable, just use `callme()` right after you create your `iframe`

Comment: To clarify, the `iframe` variable belongs to the same window as `callme()`; therefore, calling `iframe[0].ownerDocument.window.callme()` will do what you want, but there's no need for the indirection.

Comment: I need that indirection. The code example is just a simplified situation. Thanks

Comment: @danip, are you passing that variable into a function that belongs to another `window`?

Answer (score 0):

To call a parent Javascript function from an `iframe` you can use:

```
window.parent.callme();
```

Keep in mind this won't work if the iframe is on a different domain. If it's on a different domain you'll need to set both pages `document.domain` to the same value like:

```
// in both the parent and iframe
document.domain = 'site.com';
```